# JS Get Second To Last Index Of

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to get the second to last index of a character in a string.

For example, I have a string like so:

```
http://www.example.com/website/projects/2
```

I currently get the number `2` by using

`$(location).attr('href').substring($(location).attr('href').lastIndexOf('/')+1);`

But what if I want to get the word `projects`?

Can anybody help me out with this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont do much JS but I would split string at '/' and grab the before last entry in the array.

Comment: `str.lastIndexOf('/', str.lastIndexOf('/'))`. See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method:

```
var url = $(location).attr('href').split( '/' );
console.log( url[ url.length - 1 ] ); // 2
console.log( url[ url.length - 2 ] ); // projects
// etc.
```

Comment: you probably want to make a check first.

Answer (score 33):

Without using split, and a one liner to get the 2nd last index:

```
var secondLastIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/', url.lastIndexOf('/')-1)
```

The pattern can be used to go further:

```
var thirdLastIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/', (url.lastIndexOf('/', url.lastIndexOf('/')-1) -1))
```

Thanks to @Felix Kling.

> **A utility function**:

```
String.prototype.nthLastIndexOf = function(searchString, n){
    var url = this;
    if(url === null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(!n || isNaN(n) || n <= 1){
        return url.lastIndexOf(searchString);
    }
    n--;
    return url.lastIndexOf(searchString, url.nthLastIndexOf(searchString, n) - 1);
}
```

Which can be used same as lastIndexOf:

```
url.nthLastIndexOf('/', 2); //2nd last index
url.nthLastIndexOf('/', 3); //3rd last index
url.nthLastIndexOf('/'); //last index
```